# Change size of Widget Width in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to have two widgets on my home page next to each other. However I want the first widget to be 650 px, while the other to be 290px. This I am not being able to do.Can someone please help me?

The code I registered for my widgets in my theme functions.php file:

```
   register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Slider 1',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-area1 %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Side Column',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-area2 %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

Then I placed in my home page template file:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: Home Page
 */
get_header();
include('_functions/get-options.php');
?>

<?php /* Widgetised Area */ if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') ||!dynamic_sidebar('Homepage')); ?>
**<div class="widget-area1">
<?php /* Widgetised Area */ if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Slider 1')); ?>
</div>
<?php /* Widgetised Area */ if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Side Column')); ?>**

<?php /* Widgetised Area */ if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Homepage 1')); ?>
<?php /* Widgetised Area */ if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Homepage 2')); ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And the css styling I placed in the stylesheet:

```
div.widget-area1 {
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 650px;
}

div.widget-area3 {
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 290px;
}
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?The theme that I am using is Compare if that might help.

Comment: Is this site available for viewing?

Comment: yes the url is www.dailycrazydeals.com.I have placed two widget entries in the widget area Slider 1 and Side Column respectively=> Calendar and Pages list widgets

Answer (score 1):

The styles in your question like like they should work, but this is what I see in your stylesheet

```
#widget-area1 {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
}

#widget-area2 {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 290px;
}
```

These rules are in reference to an ID not to a class like you have defined in your question.

Also, you may want to remove the `clear:both` if you want them to sit side-by-side.

Comment: It's still not picking up your styles.  I don't see the correct styles in the style sheet.

Comment: You need to add your styles in the style.css of the theme you are using.  I still see the wrong styles at the bottom of the file. http://www.dailycrazydeals.com/wp-content/themes/compare/style.css

Comment: what styles should I add to make the widget side by side?

Comment: `float:left` as long a the combined widths and padding are smaller than the container div.

Comment: one should be float:left and the other float:right?Thats what I did,why does it take time to take effect?I think its because of the browser cache.

Comment: You can float both in either direction or different directions.  I prefer both to the left.  I see that your website is hosted with CloudFlare, they have set TTL's for requesting new content (Minimum edge cache expire TTL). https://www.cloudflare.com/plans

Comment: can that be changed so that i dont have any cache problem?

Comment: Develop locally then deploy to a production server when complete and ready to go live.

Comment: i checked my settings in Cloudflare.It was set to 4 hours.The minimum can be set to two hours.What should I do?Set it to maximum or minimum?